# Перезапуск игры при возобновлении из фонового режима

Tags: android, c#, unity3d

При сворачивании игры и возобновлении её, игра перезапускается, скажите что с этим можно сделать, и почему так происходит?
 Из-за нагрузки сцены ? В проекте главная сцена я бы сказал загружена объектами.

Платформа Android

Среда разработки Unity

Comment: Нужно сохранять состояние игры в методах onPause(), onStop(), onDestroy().

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, а можете пример предоставить, каким образом и что сохранять, гугл мне сейчас не дал точности

Comment: имхо самое правильное - вообще не сохранять состояние в активити. а пилить сервис. активити использовать только для отображения.

Answer (score 1):

Я так подозреваю, что процесс предоставляющий игру очень громоздкий и не выгружается в оперативную память. Потому при разворачивании приложения, все необходимые данные уже потеряны. Потому андроид перезапускает игру. Как правильно было отмечено в комментариях, необходимо переопределять метод onPause() и onResume(), например, сохранять какие нибудь данные в SharedPreference, в SQLite или просто текстовом файле в формате JSON в случае приостановки приложения, и извлекать данные из постоянной памяти при перезапуске, заново отстраивать необходимые сцены, модели и пр.

Answer (score 0):

согласно [доке](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#ActivityLifecycle), если активити скрыта другой активити, первая активити останавливается. думаю, дело именно в этом.

> If an activity is completely obscured by another activity, it is stopped.

Comment: У меня на телефоне такого нету, у других пользователей этот перезапуск есть

Comment: проверьте [onTrimMemory](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onTrimMemory(int))